# OutOfMemoryException thrown due to ImageCache Memory Leak on Android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, bitmap, image-loading

So I think I've found the source of my memory leak. Based on this article: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html it's bad to have a static Bitmap drawable and set it on an ImageView. This is because, once set (imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)) the ImageView itself is set as a **Callback** on the Bitmap.  Hence, on rotate, the Bitmap, since it's static, remains and still contains a callback to the previous ImageView, which also has a reference to the previous activity.  Hence the previous activity is not destroyed!

I believe I have a similar issue, but it's not due to a static variable, but a Singleton ImageCache class.  Basically this ImageCache is alive while the app is running and is called using getInstance(Context context).  Each bitmap that is stored in it also gets set on an ImageView at some point.

**The Memory Leak:** When the screen is rotated, the bitmap, which is still in memory, has a callback to the previous Image View.  Hence, the previous activity is not destroyed.  I don't, however, want to recycle and destroy this bitmap as it's probably used elsewhere in the app.  What I think I need to do is remove the specific ImageView being destroyed from the Bitmaps callback set.  How do I do this?  Or is my analysis completely wrong?  Appreciate the help!

**UPDATE:**

So it looks like the source of the problem is a ViewPager in my activity.  Basically, I have a Fragment ViewPager that I've added to the Header of my ListView.  That is, I call `mListView.addHeaderView(mViewPager);` This works fine, up until I rotate the screen.  Once I rotate the screen I notice the fragments are being leaked.  For example, I start the app with 3 fragments in the ViewPager.  When I rotate, I notice that the original 3 are re-created and an additional three are created.  This is not visible to the user though!  The previous three are being held onto in the background for some reason.  I'm able to see this by tracking the `onPause()` and `onCreate()` calls for the fragment.  Any idea why this is happening?

Here's some sample code:

```
mStatusView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.header,
            (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(
                    R.id.list_header));

mListView.addHeaderView(mStatusView, null /*data*/, false /*isSelectable*/);
mListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
....
mHeaderPager = (ScrollableViewPager) mStatusView.findViewById(R.id.header_pager);
```

In the above code, the mStatusView is an entire view, with other elements.  The mHeaderPager is a ViewPager within the mStatusView.

Comment: A `Bitmap` has no such callbacks, that's only a problem if you cache `BitmapDrawable`s. `getInstance(Context context)` on the other hand has a reference to a `Context` and if you store that context inside the singleton and use use the activity context you leak it.

Comment: Hmm, so I changed the getInstance(Context context) method to call context.getApplicationContext() instead.  This still causes the memory leak to occur.  The OOME crash is occurring during the XML inflate specifically on the ImageView.  Is there something I have to do with the ImageViews on onDestroy() of my fragment?

Comment: You could try to figure out what is keeping the memory: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Comment: Yeah I have been using MAT to try and find the leak.  It seems the suspect is one of my ListAdapters.  It's using the viewHolder pattern.  Not sure what could be causing the leak though.  If I use the activity context to get resources, strings, etc that should be fine right?  Apparently there's a bug with Typeface.createFromAsset() which I'm calling on almost all of my textviews.  Basically the memory created is not released according to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904.  I'm gonna fix it, but let me know if you think of anything else.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know if I need to explicitly do something about the click listeners I've attached to the adapter views during onDestroy() of the Activity?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what your adapter does. Usually no because nothing should keep the views from the adapter referenced. If you suspect it is your adapter, add some code to your question.

Comment: So I think I've found the culprit. Still not sure how to solve it.  I've updated my question.  Please Take a look.